# What is the word for a person who sets up a new business / foundation, etc

Tags: meaning

What is the word for a person who sets up a new business / foundation, etc. Founder would be too basic and does not imply setting up the structure of the organization. Same for initiator? In Dutch we use quartermaster but I have not seen this in non-army context.

11 March:
Interesting read and thanks for all the imput. Trailblazer or Groundbraker come close to what I’m trying to express. An entrepreneur invests in a company and mostly with the aim to make a profit.. Founder implies foundation only. Early or first employee implies an employment contract. The job I’m trying to describe - in one word - comes between founding / investing in a new enterprise / department and hiring regular staff – and is done on project basis mostly. You'd set up structure (organize the ‘line’ of admin, operations and finance) maybe look at the market in the broadest sense. Once organization frame of the enterprise / department is clear and set up, you’d not be involved anymore. You’d have done your job of ‘trailblazing’ ‘groundbraking ‘ ‘quarter making’ and move on to the next job.

Comment: Entrepreneur. From French.

Comment: Are you trying to differentiate between the person/people who **start** the business vs those who **set it up**? If not then founder would indeed be the right word. If so then I don't think such people are properly acknowledged in English (on both sides of the Atlantic) culture. The best I can come up with is early employee. Other than that it's job specific - first GM, first CEO, first COO, first CFO etc.

Comment: Why would founder be too basic?

Comment: It sounds like the actual job description would be for "A managing director who specialises in startups".  There isn't a single word for this AFAIK.

Answer (score 15):

If you are referring to the person who creates a new business, founder is the proper term. A founder   may or may not be the person who sets up the whole   structure.  With that respect you may refer to the managers who, following the guidelines of the founder or co-founders help to establish the whole enterprise.

[Founder](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/founder):

> - The person who creates an organization or a company is known as the founder.
> - As a noun, founder means "the beginner or originator of something." You might talk about the founder of a nation, the founder of club, or the founder of a website.

(vocabulary.com/dictionary/founder)

Comment: Of course, if the company failed, you'd call them a _flounder_.

Comment: As a concrete example, Zuckerberg is described as [CEO and **Founder** of Facebook](https://www.dw.com/en/who-is-facebook-ceo-and-founder-mark-zuckerberg/a-43118296).  As far as I know, he did the initial coding himself. So it seems to fit the question perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

Often such a person is called an

> **entrepreneur**
>   *n*   a person who organizes and manages an enterprise, esp. a business, usu. with considerable initiative.
>   [1875–80; < French: literally, one who undertakes (some task)

<sub>From [thefreedictionaryonline](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/entrepreneur)</sub>

**Edit**

For those who insist that *entrepreneur* may not be used as a de facto title, I offer [this usage breakdown of "the founder" vs. "the entrepreneur"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+entrepreneur%2Cthe+founder&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20entrepreneur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20founder%3B%2Cc0). The former still wins, but the relative trends point to "the entrepeur" as being currently on an intercepting path. The usual caveats regarding NGram usage apply, but this is at least evidence that there are not *no* cases where such a construction is used.

Comment: However, "*entrepreneur*" is a *description*, a personal characteristic, not a title or role. You wouldn't say, for example, "*Robusto is the entrepreneur of our company*"  to describe him as the one who set up the business. To me, the OP is looking for the word "*founder*", but I'm guessing he can't use it because he wants to give a person credit who was not the founder, but was engaged in some other aspect of starting up the business (the special snowflake syndrome which is so prevalent on LinkedIn).

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't say that. You're being unnecessarily prescriptive.

Comment: I could say anything, of course, free speech and all that. I'm simply reporting what people *do* and *do not* say. At the other end of the spectrum, we could coin a brand new word for OP and assign it precisely his desired meaning. But I don't think that would help him, for the obvious reasons: no one would know what he's talking about.

Comment: Now you're being silly.

Comment: I have a general policy of not engaging in or continuing debates on the Internet where the outcome would have no material impact on my life. So I'll simply say that I sincerely believe what I wrote and I also believe my position to be rational, as well as accurate and descriptive of way these words are used. It's ok if you don't agree with me, that's why SE encourages answers from diverse perspectives.

Comment: And yet you persist, despite said policy . . . note that it was you who engaged me, not the other way around.

Comment: @Robusto I thought the problem with the French was that they didn't even have a word which meant *entrepreneur*!

Comment: @WS2: You nailed it down to that one thing, did you? ^_^

Comment: @Robusto A remark (perhaps apocryphal) attributed to GWB!

Comment: *Gianni Agnelli è stato un imprenditore* (Wiki Italy)  *Gianni Agnelli was an Italian industrialist* (Wiki US) But isolated *imprenditore* is often translated as *entrepreneur* in English! Did Agnelli found FIAT, no that was his father. Giovanni Agnelli (13 August 1866 – 16 December 1945) [was an Italian **entrepreneur**, who founded Fiat car manufacturing in 1899.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Agnelli) So Robusto's answer is perfectly acceptable in my eyes.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, of course he was "*an entrepreneur **who***", but he's certainly not "*the entrepreneur **of***", as his father was "*the founder **of***". As I said, the word "*entrepreneur*" is *descriptive*, and is often applied to persons who found companies (because such people are *entrepreneurial*, or *intrepid*), but it's *not a title*, which is what OP is seeking. I feel like my comment is being misconstrued (and frankly it makes me feel bad that users are upvoting a comment which is nothing but a three-word insult leveled at me), but maybe that's my fault; maybe I am being unclear.

Comment: An entrepreneur, as I understand it to mean, is often used to describe a businessman  who sets up new and *innovative* companies. The person has initiative, drive and takes risks, such as Giovanni Agnelli, Howard Hughes etc. etc. I upvoted Robusto comment because you said: *we could coin a brand new word for OP and assign it precisely his desired meaning.* which is being silly IMO. And upvoting, downvoting is a form of free speech after all. I have had much worse (and hurtful) comments, but I have also expressed dissent and disagreements quite openly. I'm all for free speech.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Just in case it's not clear, the statement "*We could coin a brand new word...*" was supposed to be silly: it was a reductio ad absurdum. In re: entrepreneurs setting up businesses: I feel like we're going in circles on this, so I'm going to let it go.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the term "architect" is used to imply both founder and designer of an enterprise, especially if the endeavor is sufficiently complex that some sort of construct is involved.

> ar·chi·tect  (är′kĭ-tĕkt′) n.
>
> 1. One who designs and supervises the construction of buildings or other large structures.
> 2. One that plans, devises, or organizes something: a country that was the war's chief architect.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/architect

Answer (score 4):

Besides being called a "**[founding father](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/founding+father)**", that person could be a **[groundbreaker](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/groundbreaker)**.

- founding father : who founds or establishes something.
- someone who helps to open up a new line of research or technology or art
  ≡ *pioneer, trailblazer↔conceiver, mastermind, **originator*** - someone who creates new things.

(Vocabulary.com/TFD)

Answer (score 2):

"What is the word for a person who sets up a new business / foundation, etc."

The answer to this question lies in your definition of "sets up."

If by "sets up" you mean "*files the appropriate paperwork with the state so that company is an official entity*", then this person could be an accountant, attorney, secretary, administrative assistant, etc.

If you mean "*provides initial funding to support the business*" then this person could be an (angel) investor.

If you mean "*envisions and executes the business strategy with direct and commensurate exposure to risk and reward*", then you may be referring to an entrepreneur.

Answer (score 1):

I'm inclined to go with the previous suggestions (founder seems like a fine word), but in some situations "creator" might be useful.  One wouldn't say that Jim is the creator of IBM, for example, but you might say that someone was the creator of a program, a single-purpose startup, or similar.  As an example, Maria Montessori was probably the "founder" of the first Montessori school, but might be the "creator" of the Montessori educational system.

Answer (score 0):

One term that no one mentioned as far as I can tell is "Principal". That incorporates Founder and Manager, but it also quite formal.

Comment: Hello, suse. Please examine the standard of the format of the two most upvoted answers: references with links and attributions.

Answer (score -1):

Venturer and argonaut are a couple of interesting, related terms.

Answer (score -3):

I’m not sure if this helps but I was looking for the same word you are - as I’m one of those people, and trying to figure out a way to describe myself in a professional manner to others. So I've been doing some research, and I think the term we’re both looking for is "right-hand-man/woman". Definition - very imortant assistant.

Comment: You believe that this is what the question is asking for?  You’re a hand?  Who’s the head and body?  You’re an assistant?  Assistant to whom?  I don’t see anything in the question that suggests that it is looking for a word for the *second* in command.